# Союз "покуда" (значение = пока)

Tags: союзы

В одном толковом словаре стоит, что **покуда** это разговорный союз (вообще-то стоит "*разг.-сниж*.", но я совсем не знаю, что "*сниж*." обозначает). 
В другом стоит, что это устаревший союз. 
Мне как не носителю языка совсем неизвестны это тонкости, но очень нужно знать, устаревший это союз или используется сегодня в разговорной речи.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В русском языке (по степени литературности) речи выделяют три стиля речи: высокий (книжный) стиль – средний( нейтральный) стиль – сниженный (разговорный) стиль.

ПОКУДА, нареч. и союз. Разг. = Пока. П. работаю - отдохни. * Съел полпуда, сыт покуда (Посл.).

В современной **нейтральной** речи союз "покуда" используется не часто, хотя в художественной литературе ХІХ века он был ближе к среднему стилю. В настоящий момент он в большей степени характерен для народно-поэтической речи, для передачи просторечного языка персонажей в художественной литературе, также может использоваться в публицистических произведениях полемического характера.

Примеры

О женихах и слышать не хочет, **покуда** не воротится её родимый батюшка (С. Т. Аксаков. Aленький цветочек).

Они помолчали, **покуда** лакей расставлял чайный прибор (Л. Н. Толстой).

А **покуда** этого не будет ― голод всегда будет (Л. Н. Толстой. Письма Н. С. Лескову).

― Вот и хорошо, ― говорю, ― мы с вами посидим на скамеечке, **покуда** Анна Моисеевна придёт (Анатолий Рыбаков).

Как преодолеть этот порочный заколдованный круг в России? Ответа **покуда** нет (2003).

Answer (score 0):

> но я совсем не знаю, что "сниж." обозначает

Сниженный: грубый, площадной, некультурный.

В разговорной речи "покуда" используется именно в сниженном стиле. Иногда - с ироническим подтекстом.
Зачем вам "очень нужно знать" такие вещи? Вы разведчик и по легенде - русский?)))

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Задание было определить стилистический регистр одного предложения. 
perdón, последнее предложение не поняла. "площадной" тоже...